# Nodejs variable can't pass to event listener

Tags: javascript, node.js

this.name couldn't pass to my function event emitter,  Any idea?
My code:

```
function lightwareTx(name,ip){
this.name = name;
This. IP = IP;

this.connect = function(){
    this.client = net.createConnection(10001,this.ip);
    this.reconnectSts = true;

    this.client.on('connect', function(){
        console.log(this.name);
        //undefined
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of how the `this` keyword is being bind. I strongly suggest reading e.g. [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to learn how this fundamental process works. In your case, `this` within the callback was most probably bound to a global scope (which is `process` object in node environment and `window` in web browsers, unless you use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)).

As a quick workaroud, you can attach `this` to a variable, and use it later.

```
function lightwareTx(name,ip){
    var self = this;
    this.name = name;
    This. IP = IP;

    this.connect = function(){
         this.client = net.createConnection(10001,this.ip);
         this.reconnectSts = true;

         this.client.on('connect', function(){
             console.log(self.name);
             //name
         });
    } 
}
```

Comment: @KrzysztofZbiciński, Thank you for your explanation, not only solve my problem but taught me a lesson too. Appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `this` is pointing to another context. You have two options here:

- add `var self = this;` to `connect` function and then call `console.log(self.name);`
- use `bind` this way - so you can change the context:

  `this.client.on('connect', function(){
          console.log(this.name);
      }.bind(this))`